# Google Admin SDK client library generates SSL3_GET_RECRD:wrong version number error when attempting to get a user

Tags: python, ssl, google-apps, google-api-python-client

I am trying to use Google Admin SDK API and python client libraries to manage my Google Apps users. I am trying to get a certain user, bssl.SSLError: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:1429:

```
error:1408F10B:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number
```

My code is (mostly) as follows:

```
import httplib2
from apiclient import errors
from apiclient.discovery import build

client_email = 'service_account_email@developer.gserviceaccount.com'
with open("service_account_certificate.p12") as f:
  private_key = f.read()
OAUTH_SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user'
credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(client_email, private_key, OAUTH_SCOPE, sub="admin@domain.com" )
http = httplib2.Http()
http = credentials.authorize(http)

directory_service = build('admin', 'directory_v1', http=http)

user = directory_service.users().get(userKey="someuser@domain.com").execute()
```

That last line seems to be the one causing the issue. Any hints?

E.

Answer (score 1):

> SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number

The server no longer supports SSLv3. You need to upgrade your pip modules and/or Python.